# Google Maps Business Listing - Address Visible Only to Me

Tags: google-my-business

When I look at my business on Google Maps, it only lists my city and state. However, if I go to the administration - it shows my complete address, but it says it's only visible to me. (Google My Business -> Info)

How do I make my address visible to all?...

Comment: @pnuts Yes I have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was why:

"I also serve customers at my business address. (Your address will be hidden from the public if this box isn't checked.)"